# RE: How Would I Change a .txt File to a .msp or .gpx for Google Earth-GPS Usage?

Tags: python-2.7, gps, beagleboneblack, google-earth, gpsbabel

I have a file called TacoII.txt. It is a kml file in .txt format. I wanted to add this file to Google Earth to track items I attach my BeagleBone Black and a GPS module (SIM28). I downloaded GPSBabel and tried to change file types. I was successful at changing the file type once with a specific routine.

With this routine, the .mps file was not able to be displayed in Google Earth.

If anyone is coming across difficulties with this notion, please reply. I would like to first track me and the BBB w/ GPS on Google Earth.

Seth

P.S. If you need any other info, do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried GPSbabel and failed at using it. I then researched their site more and looked around. After looking around I found that the skeleton file, this .py file that was produced by Mr. Whorton, was correct and his KML file, the file I needed, was incorrect for Google Earth.

I changed the KML file to suit the needs of Google Earth:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
```

This is the second line that was needed for the Google Earth KML file. Oh and I had to use a "shady" conversion tool online that changed my file to .gpx format from .txt.

Seth

P.S. Please let me know if anyone else needs help with this specific issue.